# Use an existing Network Drive in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, network-drive, bcs

Hello stackoverflow community,

some days ago i installed SharePoint 2013 Enterprise Server in the 64 Bit Version.
For many days i tried to map our existing Networkfolder from our Company in SharePoint 2013. I searched the internet for a long time and even if i find someone with the same problem in a forum, he/she has no responses to the thread.

I know it is possible to create a new SharePoint Drive and Map it into my explorer, but thats not the solution i was looking for.

Do you have any ideas how to solve the problem? So is it possible to use an existing Network Drive in SharePoint 2013?

Do i need Business Connectiviy Services? If so, does anyone has a Workaround or a Walktrough for me?

Sincerly,

Philipp

Answer (score 1):

There is no good OOTB solution for this. Especially if you would like the mapped drives behave like a document library and have search crawlers index the files.

For a very small scale and limited workaround a Page Viewer webpart can be pointed at a shared folder, however this will only display in IE in a low security intranet mode and the contents of the shared folder will not be crawled.

MS would suggest a content migration of your network drives across into the SP databases.

So the only real option is 3rd party. Something like this: [AvePoint SharePoint File Share Integration](http://www.avepoint.com/sharepoint-connector-docave/)

Disclaimer: Have not used this plugin and cannot vouch for its usability.